# Properties of the Double Layer Potential

Tags: integration, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

Consider the double layer potential
$$
 W_{\nu}(x) = \int_{\partial\Omega} \nu(y) \frac{\partial}{\partial n_y}\left( \frac{1}{|x - y|} \right) d \sigma_y
$$
for a bounded region $\Omega \in \mathbb R^3$ with a constant function $\nu(y) \equiv \nu_0$.

a) Show that $W_{\nu}(x) = 0$ for $x \notin \overline \Omega$.

b) Compute $W_{\nu}^i(x) := \lim_{\xi \to x, \xi \in \Omega} W_{\nu}(\xi)$ for $x \in \partial \Omega$.

c) Show, with b), that $W_{\nu}(x) = -4\pi \nu_0$ for all $x \in \Omega$.

Any hints how to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
    \int_{\partial\Omega}\frac{\partial}{\partial n_y}\frac{1}{|x-y|}\,dS(y)=\int_{\partial\Omega} \nabla_{y}\frac{1}{|x-y|}\cdot\,d\overline{S}(y).
$$
If $x \notin\Omega$, then the right side becomes, by the Divergence Theorem,
$$
        \int_{\Omega}\nabla_{y}^{2}\frac{1}{|x-y|^{2}}dV(y) = 0.
$$
If $x \in \Omega$, let $\Omega_{\epsilon}$ be the region obtained by deleting a sphere of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $x$ from $\Omega$. Then the boundary of $\Omega_{\epsilon}$ is $\partial\Omega\cup \partial B_{\epsilon}(x)$, but the outward normal on $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ points toward the inside point $x$. Because of the inward pointing normal on $\partial B_{\epsilon}$,
$$
       \int_{\partial B_{\epsilon}(x)}\nabla_{y}\frac{1}{|x-y|}\cdot d\overline{S}(y) 
    = 4\pi, \;\;\; \epsilon > 0.
$$
Now the first line of this post may be written as
$$
         -4\pi + \int_{\partial\Omega_{\epsilon}}\nabla_{y}\frac{1}{|x-y|}\cdot d\overline{S}(y)=-4\pi.
$$
This type of technique is farily general because a typical volume integral in the subject can typically be written as a limit as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ of the volume integral where a sphere of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $x$ is omitted.

Comment: where do you need that $x \notin \Omega$ for part a)?

Comment: I am not sure about $$ \int_{\partial B_{\varepsilon}(x)} \nabla_y \frac{1}{|x-y|} \cdot d\overline{S}(y) = 4\pi $$ we have $$ \nabla_y \frac{1}{|x-y|} = -\frac{1}{|x-y|^3} \cdot (x-y)$$ and the (inward pointing normal) is $$ \frac{x-y}{|x-y|} $$ so that this integral becomes $$\int_{\partial B_{\varepsilon}(x)} \frac{-1}{|x-y|^2} dx = \int_{\partial B_{\varepsilon}(x)} \frac{-1}{\varepsilon^2} dx = -\frac{4\pi}{\varepsilon}?$$ Which is differenent from your result?

Comment: You need that $x\notin\Omega$ to apply the divergence theorem on $\Omega$. The divergence theorem does not allow singularities inside $\Omega$. That's also the reason why you must cirumvent the singularity when $x$ is inside $\Omega$. The integral which gives you $4\pi$ is a surface integral. The surface area over $|x|=\epsilon$ is $4\pi \epsilon^{2}$. And you have a function inside that is $1/|x|^{2}$. So everything cancels perfectly to give you a constant.

Comment: Yes, regarding the surface element, I saw it just in the moment your comment came, so this is clear to me now :) But then it is still wrong up to a minus sign, or you forgot the minus sign in your post I guess... and also what about part b)... do you have mentioned it?

Comment: I'm always messing up the negative signs. This is the correct arugment, once all the signs are correct. And, it's rigorous, without a bunch of $\delta$ function hand-waving. In fact, the argument extends considerably. Keep this in mind: the outward normal on $B_{\epsilon}$ points toward the inside of the sphere because the outside of $\Omega\setminus B_{\epsilon}$ is inside the sphere, and that's where we're applying the Divergence Theorem.

Comment: $\nabla_{y}((|x-y|^{2})^{-1/2})=(-1/2)(|x-y|^{2})^{-3/2}2(y-x)=-|x-y|^{-3}(y-x)$.

Comment: In your last comment it should be $2(x-y)$ not $2(y-x)$? And regarding part b), is $W_{\nu}^i(x) = 0$?

Comment: You're differentiating with respect to $y$.

Comment: Yes, okay, there comes a minus sign! :) Okay, and for b), is $W_{\nu}^i(x) = 0$?

Comment: For your problem, $W_{\nu}^{i}$ is constant inside $\Omega$, and another constant outside. That makes the limit constant, depending on whether you're coming from the inside or from the outside.

Comment: I come from the inside, so it equals $4\pi \nu_0$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I understand. Nice problem to post.